# Use input javascript to redirect to input url

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, search, input

So u have a search box and type there a word/code/something and it redirects u to example.com/the-input
How can I make this?
Below is my not working code.

(I'm pretty new to javascript and tryed to use my knowledge from other languages sry if that sound stupid )

```
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" class="searchTerm" id="link" placeholder="Write your code here...">
  <button onclick="search" type="submit" class="searchButton">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </button>
</div>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function search() {
    var url = "http://www.example.com" + link;
    window.location = url;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Specify your question, please - what is your goal, where is a problem, how can we help?

Comment: U have a search box and type there a word/code/something and it redirects u to https://example.com/the-input

Comment: redirect when the search button clicked right?

Comment: Yeah redirect the input when click the button

Comment: I'm sorry, it wasn't clear for a new member - edit your question (which now is not a question) and add this information - what help you need? What is your question?

Comment: `onclick="search()"`

Comment: `var url = "http://www.example.com/" + document.getElementById("link").value.split(" ").join("-");`

Comment: If you are coding the other side also just us a form

Comment: You are welcome!
See my answer below which incorporates my suggestions.
Please select and up-vote my answer if helpful - that's how we advance here at s.o..
(up-vote when you have 15+ reputation points).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function search() {
  // The following line of code was split for readability
  // var url = "http://www.example.com/"+document.getElementById("link").value.split(" ").join("-");
  var url = "http://www.example.com/"+
      document.getElementById("link").value
      .split(" ").join("-");
  console.log(url);
  // window.location = url;
}
```

```html
Search term(s) <input id="link" onchange="search()">
<button onclick="search()">Go to page+dash split search</button><br>
Will log to console for demonstration purpose.
```